# Is it possible to use vue-router without a component in vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a very simple page, just a few lines of code and I would like to use vue-router without a vue-component.

I would like to get the `string "my-search-query"` after the root:

```
www.example.com/my-search-query
```

and use it in my main Vue() object. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: If that's all you want to use vue-router for, just use ```window.location.pathname```

Comment: @tom_h how would i be notified when the path would change to "my-other-search-query"? sorry for noob questions, i am just beginning to learn vue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to use `vue-router` without a `vue-component` and still be notified about path changes in the main Vue() app object:

You can get the `"my-search-query"` string from `www.example.com/#/my-search-query` like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/:question' }
  ]
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  watch: {
    '$route.params.question': function(newVal, oldVal) {
      alert(newVal === 'my-search-query');
    }
 }
});
```

Thanks to @samayo for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I did this approach when I was in a situation where the component would always be the same so router-view seemed redundant, but i quickly found myself in a weird place trying to handle all the watchers manually. I think in the future I would use <router-view> anyway and try and hook up query/param passing using the `props` option in the route itself. (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode)

Answer (score 3):

Since the router is part of your view model instance, you can create a computed function that returns the path value of the router. For example, you can do the following:

```
data: function() {
    router: new VueRouter()
},
computed: function() {
    routerPath: function() {
        return this.router.currentRoute.path;
    }
},
watch: function() {
    routerPath: function(val) {
        switch(val) {
            case '/':
                // @TODO: logic for home
                break;
            case '/path1':
                var query = this.router.currentRoute.query;
                // @TODO: logic form query params
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

With this, the router will manage the history for you, but you don't have to divide your code up into components. For example, I have a pretty small page and just wanted to put everything into the same viewModel without breaking everything up into components.

Answer (score 2):

As tom_h has said you can use `window.location.pathname` if you just want to get the path name. If you want to be notified when this pathname changes, then first initialize it to your data(){} object and watch it as:

```
data () {
  return {
    path: window.location.pathname
  }
},

watch: {
  path (newpath, oldpath) {
    alert('location path just changed from ' + newpath + ' to ' + oldpath )
  }
}
```

Comment: This will notify when `path` changes, but not when `window.location.pathname` changes.

Comment: But path will change when the window pathname also changes

Comment: Could you show me an example where `location.pathname` changes and your watcher actually fires?

Comment: If you are persistent then maybe I was wrong as I assumed that would the case ..but still I will test it and update the answer .. i'm on mobile right noe

Comment: @samayo i have tried as you suggested, but when i type "my-search-query" behind my root and press enter, all i get is a 404 from my Apache server. sorry for my noob questions, i am new to javascript / vue.

Comment: Reason I asked is I don't believe this will work. Data is only ever initialized once. `window.location` is a non reactive, read only object. Changing the location reloads the page.